# Is there a limit to how close faraway objects can get due to the conservation of angular momentum?

Tags: special-relativity, angular-momentum

Say a 1kg object is going 1 meter/sec tangentially to a point 600,000,000 meters away, its angular momentum is $$1kg*1m/s*600,000,000 meters$$ If it were to decrease its radius to the point similar to the image below by getting closer to the point then we will see an increase to radial velocity. Since there is a limit to velocity, c, then there must be a limit to how close we can get to the point.

So I figure the answer has to do with relativistic angular momentum but that math is a bit above my understanding. I assume it also has to do with shedding energy in other forms like gravitational waves when BHs merge?

[image: example]

Comment: After choosing an origin, the angular momentum is conserved if there is no applied torques. But changing the origin, its value changes.

Comment: Have you tried calculating the angular momentum of this object for a given origin? You would see that it is, in fact, constant.

Comment: @Tratticus Are you asking me that or the previous commenter?

Answer (score 3):

The mass factor in moment of inertia varies with velocity as $\gamma m$ where $\gamma$ is the tangent-velocity dependent [Lorentz factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_factor). Angular momentum can thus take any value zero to infinity for any nonzero radius as tangent velocity ranges from $0$ to $c$.

Comment: @g s I am happy to select this answer as the right answer but was hoping you could help me understand why the answer below is incorrect or worded incorrectly. The way I understand your answer is by doing the same math as I outline below.

Answer (score -1):

I know I asked the question but I think I have figured it out. Since you can not get above the speed of light then the only other variable that can change as you decrease the radius is the mass. When accounting for what relativity would do to speed if we were to go to 1 meter away you would end up with a velocity of 268,179,621 m/s when calculating for "relativistic mass" for that velocity you end up with 2.2373 kg. If you plug both the new speed and mass into angular momentum $m*r*v$ you end up with the same angular momentum we started with meaning we have conservation with no limit to how close an object can get to the point it is rotating around.

Comment: Conservation of momentum does not work like this. The momentum about a given point does not have to be equal to the momentum about a different point. And also, the tangential speed (actually linear speed) is the same when measured from all reference points as long as they are rest relative to each other. If you measure the speed from 600,000 km away or from 6 cm away, it is still 1 m/s (as long as the two reference points are reciprocally at rest). This has noting to do with relativistic mechanics, by the way.

Comment: @nasu just to use the old example of a figure skater spinning. The object in the question is their hand when extended out. As they pull it in it increases velocity. From a far away distance wouldn't that velocity grow to be relativistic when getting pulled in? Perhaps I'm confused?

Comment: No, your situation is not the same. For the skater the angular momentum is calculated about the same axis, before and after he moves his arms. You are just changing the axis. It is like saying that changing your position relative to the skater will change his velocity, without him doing anything.

Comment: @nasu ok I think I fixed the question